# Multiple front page aliases

Tags: 8, routes

This question may be simple and I'm overlooking the answer, but I am trying to add routes that are front page aliases and there doesn't seem to be an obvious solution.

Basically what I want is to add more front pages, because I want to parse the values in JS, and not through php.

Example:

If the front is /node I also want /variable/value to go to the front.

Can I do this through my routing.yml?

Note: I'm not looking for a redirect to / or /node because I need the url values.

Comment: Why can't you simply use redirects?

Comment: @AjitS I want to use the path values, a redirect will change the path.